# Minimal Keras + Sound Neural Network

Tags: numpy, scipy, keras

I'm trying to build the hello world of audio data and keras. I'm failing to grasp what it means to vectorize your data.

I tried adapting https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/ to sound data.

my code on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/morenoh149/sound-hello-world)

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import os
import numpy
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

train_dir = '../input/traditional-flute-dataset/audio'
audio_file_path = os.path.join(train_dir, os.listdir(train_dir)[0])
rate, audio = scipy.io.wavfile.read(audio_file_path)
processed_audio = numpy.reshape(audio, (1,len(audio)))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=processed_audio.shape))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(processed_audio, ['flute'], epochs=20)
```

error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1018624)
```

audio.shape is `(1018624,)`. The answer should be a minimal fully executable keras example, processing more than 1 audio file, ideally on kaggle.

What are the pros and cons of doing a 1Dconvolution vs convolving over the sounds' spectrogram as if it were an image?

EDIT: the immediate problem was solved, I needed to specify the dimensions of an example sound to the first Keras layer. Checkout [Sound Hello World](https://www.kaggle.com/morenoh149/sound-hello-world) where I'll be fleshing out an end-to-end, executable example.

Comment: What is `data.shape`? The error is related to the shape mismatch of that.

Comment: @nuric I've reworked the example a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll train without errors by changing the last Dense to more than 1 class (1 doesn't make sense and it errors):

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

And with this:

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(audio, 0)
y_train = np.array([[1., 0.]])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)
```

I see you also changed your `input_shape` - don't. Set it back to: `audio.shape`.

To avoid confusion, here's a whole snippet based on your original code:

```
fs, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('1.wav')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=data.shape))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_train = np.expand_dims(data, 0)
y_train = np.array([[1., 0.]])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

Comment: can you expand on `np.array([[1., 0.]])` and how to make this more label-like? say `np.array([['foo', 'bar']])`.

Comment: This is not really related to the original question. If you want to use text labels from an array you can just use the indexes from that array. e.g. `labels = ['foo', 'bar']; y_train_data = ['foo']; y_train = np.array([[labels.index(label) for label in y_train_data]])`  (and I forgot to turn the indexes into one-hot at the end)

Comment: To clarify: the `[1., 0.]` in my code is just a one-hot encoding of the index 0.

Comment: for multiclass they use `keras.utils.to_categorical` a lot to one hot encode the label data

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer but I'll continue fleshing out a good full example of a keras sound NN that makes sense.